# creating a simple kernel module using VirtualBox which outputs the elements of a C struct

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel, virtualbox, kernel-module

I am attempting to create a simple kernel module using Oracle VirtualBox.  The module simply instantiates instances of a C struct and outputs the elements of those struct instances using a printk statement.  The problem is that I am getting no output of the elements of my struct instances

the make file code is as follows:

```
obj-m += simple.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=S(PWD) clean
```

the companion file is named simple.c and is as follows:

```
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/list.h>
#include<linux/types.h>

struct birthday{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    struct list_head list;
}

//defines and initializes the variable birthday_list of type struct list_head
static LIST_HEAD(birthday_list);

//create and initialize instances of struct birthday
struct birthday *person2;
person2 = kmalloc(sizeof(*person2), GFP_KERNEL);
person2->day = 11;
person2->month = 9;
person2->year = 1985;
INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person2->list);

//this function is called when the module is loaded
int simple_init(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading Module\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "Person 2 day is: %d \n", person2->day);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Person 2 month is: %d \n", person2->month);
    printk(KERN_INFO "person 2 year is: %d \n", person2->year);

    return 0;
}

//this function is called when the module is removed
int simple_exit(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Removing module\n");
}

//macros for registering module entry and exit points
module_init(simple_init);
module_exit(siple_exit);
```

}

The problem is that the only output I am getting is the first print statement "Loading Module", the other print statements which are supposed to output the elements of the instance of my struct do not output anything at all.  Is something wrong with my syntax?

The procedure I am using, is:

1. type, on the command line, the command: "make" in order to compile the file simple.c
2. Next, type the command: "sudo insmod simple.ko" to load the kernel module.
3. Next, type the command: "dmesg" to see the output of my printk statements.

When I follow this procedure, the only output I get is: "Loading Module" I get no output from the instance of my struct

Comment: I get lots of errors when compiling this.  Please post the *exact* contents of your source file.

Comment: Probably, the phase `//create and initialize instances of struct birthday` belongs to `simple_init` function. But it smells like this is not the only inconsistency between the code you **show** us and the code which is **actually compiled** and run. In the current code `printk` statements a good by themselves, and should provide correct output.